# Not able to use cloudfront URL with flexpaper

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, amazon-cloudfront, flexpaper

I am using flexpaper classic trial version that accepts the swf files to display documents in my rails web application.

I have my content available on s3 within a private distibution, that can be accessible only using the cloudfront signed urls. But when i provide that url to flexplayer, for example :

http://d2qpwcrmsdq67g.cloudfront.net/172/ebooks/1357d6f7c32e68f27caf63b84085bd22.swf?Expires=1416463422&Signature=signature&Key-Pair-Id=key-pair-id

```
$('#documentViewer').FlexPaperViewer(
        { config : {

            SWFFile : "http://d2qpwcrmsdq67g.cloudfront.net/172/ebooks/1357d6f7c32e68f27caf63b84085bd22.swf?Expires=1416463422&Signature=signature&Key-Pair-Id=key-pair-id",

            Scale : 0.6,
            ZoomTransition : 'easeOut',
            ZoomTime : 0.5,
            ZoomInterval : 0.1,
            FitPageOnLoad : false,
            FitWidthOnLoad : false,
            PrintEnabled : false,
            FullScreenAsMaxWindow : false,
            ProgressiveLoading : true,
            MinZoomSize : 0.2,
            MaxZoomSize : 5,
            SearchMatchAll : false,
            RenderingOrder : 'flash',
            ViewModeToolsVisible : false,
            ZoomToolsVisible : false,
            NavToolsVisible : false,
            CursorToolsVisible : false,
            SearchToolsVisible : false,
            WMode : 'window',
            localeChain: 'en_US'
        }}
);
```

it search for the crossdomain.xml which can't be found as cloudfront uses a default crossdomain.xml that can't be overriden. Therefore i get the following error on my browser console.

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) http://d2qpwcrmsdq67g.cloudfront.net/crossdomain.xml

Is there any way i can use cloudfront url with flexpaper.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I would imagine you actually have to supply this bit of the url `Key-Pair-Id=key-pair-id` with your key pair id.

Comment: Yes, i am supplying a proper signed url to flexpaper, as when i open that url directly in browser it provides me with swf file.

Comment: Have you configured your Amazon S3 bucket for CORS? See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/header-caching.html#header-caching-web-cors

Comment: Thanks John, and apologies for late reply.I had configured CORS in bucket, now all working fine on mozilla but another issue in chrome-
XMLHttpRequest cannot load. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
When i hit the cloudfront url with curl -i -H command then i am getting 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin="*"' in the Header